# Can't connect to ftp server when adding a port number in the script (.bat)

Tags: batch-file, command-line, ftp

I have this script to zip a file and send it via ftp, and works perfectly except when I change the default port.

I have this:

```
SET ftphost=xx.xxx.xxx.xx
```

and want to add a port. I tried with this:
The ipadress followed by a space and port, but I get help content instead of the connection.

```
SET ftphost=xx.xxx.xxx.xx 999
```

and with colon instead of space and port, and I get "unknown host"

```
SET ftphost=xx.xxx.xxx.xx:999
```

This is the hole script

```
REM ECHO year=%year%
SET month=%date:~5,2%
IF "%month:~0,1%" == " " SET month=0%month:~1,1%
REM ECHO month=%month%
SET day=%date:~8,2%
IF "%day:~0,1%" == " " SET day=0%day:~1,1%
REM ECHO day=%day%

REM set filename with current timestamp
SET filename=file_%year%%month%%day%_%hour%%min%%secs%.zip

REM to ask to set zip password
REM SET /p zippass=Set zip password:

REM to set the zip password instead of asking for it
SET zippass="p"

REM to ask for parameters
REM SET /p ftphost=Enter ftphost:
REM SET /p username=Enter user:
REM SET /p userpass=Enter password:

REM to save the parameters instead of asking for them
SET ftphost=xx.xxx.xxx.xx
SET username=all
SET userpass=12345

SET encrypt_headers=
REM SET encrypt_headers=-mhe

START /wait 7za.exe a %filename% * -r -mx9 -p%zippass% %encrypt_headers% -x!7za.exe -x!zip_ftp.bat -x!zip_ftp_ask.bat
SET file=%filename%

@ECHO off
ECHO user %username%> ftpcmd.dat
ECHO %userpass%>> ftpcmd.dat
ECHO bin>> ftpcmd.dat
ECHO put %file%>> ftpcmd.dat
ECHO quit>> ftpcmd.dat

ftp -n -s:ftpcmd.dat %ftphost%
DEL ftpcmd.dat
PAUSE
```

Is there a different sintax or a parameter to add the port to the ftp?

Comment: Instead of specifying the host on the call to FTP, try adding `open %ftphost% port` to the top of your ftpcmd.dat file.

Comment: In fact that worked, thanks!, i'll put the script

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As [Matt Williamson](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2282445/matt-williamson) said, adding the command open host with the port `open 172.xx.xx.xx 22 >  ftpcmd.dat`  to  the was the solution, dont know why it cant read the address directly from the script.

Here is the working ftp part of the script:

```
SET ftphost=172.xxx.xxx.xx 22    
ECHO open %ftphost% > ftpcmd.dat
ECHO user %username%>> ftpcmd.dat
ECHO %userpass%>> ftpcmd.dat
ECHO bin>> ftpcmd.dat
ECHO put %file%>> ftpcmd.dat
ECHO quit>> ftpcmd.dat

ftp -n -s:ftpcmd.dat
PAUSE
```

This should avoid the window showing the help content of ftp instead of trying to connect.